# I deleted my post but it isn't gone

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I deleted one of my previous posts, but it still can be seen. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 4):

*You* can still see the post, and that is by design; you might want to undelete it after a while if you found out how to improve it. Most other users cannot see it; you can test this yourself by opening the post in a private browser window (or a different browser where you're not logged in). It should look something like this:

[image]

Other users with at least 10k reputation can also see it *if they have a link to it*. And finally ♦ moderators and staff can see all your deleted posts. For example, if a user decides to rage quit, deleting valuable content, they can step in and rescue the content.

For more information, check out the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.